# .htaccess not redirecting properly on webhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website http://alburoojschool.org and this is the .htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex home.php index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule home home.php

RewriteRule ^pages/([^\.]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^news-list/([^\.]+)$ news-list.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^iq-admin/([^\.]+)$ iq-admin/$1.php
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ latest-news.php?id=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^events-list/([^\.]+)$ events-list.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^events/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ upcoming-events.php?id=$1&post=$2 [NC,L]
```

when I click on http://alburoojschool.org/news-list/1, it says it's a redirect loop but works fine on localhost. Please help me.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess in `/news-list/` directory?

Comment: @CD001 for some mysterious reason, it works well on localhost. and on web host, it is being redirected to `http://alburoojschool.org/news-list/home` though it's not being redirected to the news-list/home anywhere in htaccess or href link. (you can refer the website if you can please)

Comment: @anubhava no the .htaccess file is in base directory.

Comment: Any redirects happening in news-list.php?

Comment: Sorry, there was redirection `if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
  header("home");`
 }` which i have changed to `if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
  header("location:http://alburoojschool.org");
 }`. but now it is being redirected to home which means it is not getting `?id=$1`.  but it is able to in localhost . Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few potential pitfalls but I think this is your main culprit.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule home home.php
```

You probably want to ensure that `home` is a complete phrase and redirect relative to the document root like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /home.php
```

With what you've got an URL like `/news-list/home` will hit that first match and attempt to redirect to `/news-list/home.php` which, I'm assuming, doesn't exist so it'll attempt to redirect (again) to `/news-list/home.php` and so on.

You should probably update all your redirects so that they're relative to the docroot.